# Error accessing analytics API with ruby gem

Tags: ruby, youtube, rubygems, youtube-api

I am having problems to obtain the the number of views per video. What i got is so far:

First of all I logged in as the youtube user and went to the developer console. There I granted access to the Youtube APIs. I also generated a server key with a p12 file, which I downloaded.

```
key_file = "***/***.p12"
issuer = "****@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
```

Then I initiate the youtube client using the ruby library. I know I need two scopes:

```
data_scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
analytics_scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly"
```

Finally its time to create the actual clients

```
# Youtube Data and Analytics Client
$youtube_client = Google::APIClient.new(
     :application_name => "Youtube Monitoring",
     :application_version => "0.1")
$youtube_data_config = $youtube_client.discovered_api('youtube', 'v3')
$youtube_analytics_config = $youtube_client.discovered_api('youtubeAnalytics', 'v1')
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(key_file, 'notasecret')
$youtube_client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :scope => [data_scope, analytics_scope],
  :issuer => issuer,
  :signing_key => key)
$youtube_client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
```

Once this client is created I want to retrieve all of the videos that I uploaded:

```
video_ids = $youtube_client.execute(:api_method => $youtube_data_config.search.list, :parameters => {:for_mine => true, :maxResults => 50, :part => "snippet"})
```

And for each video I'd like to retrieve the number of views it got in a certain time frame. Lets take the last video of the retrieved ones:

```
video_id = video_ids.data.items.last.id.videoId
channel_id = video_ids.data.items.last.snippet.channelId
```

Now for this video I'd like to get the number of views:

```
analytics = $youtube_client.execute(:api_method => $youtube_analytics_config.reports.query, :parameters => {"ids" => "channel==#{channel_id}", "filters" => "video==#{video_id}", "start-date" => "2013-01-01", "end-date" => "2014-01-10", "metrics" => "views"})
```

An this is where I am getting problems. I am getting a forbidden call:

```
body=>"{\n \"error\": {\n  \"errors\": [\n   {\n    \"domain\": \"global\",\n    \"reason\": \"forbidden\",\n    \"message\": \"Forbidden\"\n   }\n  ],\n  \"code\": 403,\n  \"message\": \"Forbidden\"\n }\n}\
```

I am puzzled why this doesn't work. I've tried a number of times but always with the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can also add that when going through the web interface of google api explorer and authenticating this works fine. So it must be something with the outh server p12 authentication, but it is not throwing any problems when authenticating.

Comment: 403 means I am not allowed to access my own resources how can this be?